# Correct scale of density plots with multiple groups using GGally in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

I'm trying to visualize a dataset using ggpairs from GGally library in R. I want to have a diagonal with density plots of each variable separated by a grouping variable. I'm not being able to get the right plots because of a scale issue. To illustrate my point, I'll use the following artificial dataset:

```
group=as.numeric(cut(runif(100),c(0,1/2,1),c(1,2)))
x=rnorm(100,group,1)
x[group==1]=(x[group==1])^2
y=2*x+rnorm(100,0,0.1)
data=data.frame(group=as.factor(group),x=x,y=y)
```

Using ggpairs, I get the following plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)    
ggpairs(data,columns = 2:3,colour="group")
```

[image]

Now, compare the top left plot to the density plot of variable x obtained using plain ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, colour = group)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

We can see that the y scale of the red and blue curves in ggpairs (the first figure) are not the same, which may lead to misleading conclusions. How can I correct this in ggpairs?

Comment: make the individual plots yourself and use `grid.arrange`, perhaps, rather than rely on ggally? or file an issue with the maintainer `Barret Schloerke <schloerke at gmail.com>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from the developers:

> You are correct. they are not displaying correctly. :-(
>
> With the current CRAN release, please try the following...
>
> ```
> set.seed(1234)
> group = as.numeric(cut(runif(100),c(0,1/2,1),c(1,2)))
> x = rnorm(100,group,1)
> x[group == 1] = (x[group == 1])^2
> y = (2 * x) + rnorm(100,0,0.1)
> data = data.frame(group = as.factor(group), x = x, y = y)
>
> library(ggplot2)
> library(GGally)    
>
> # # bad example
> # ggpairs(data,columns = 2:3,colour="group")
>
>
> ggally_correct_diag_densityDiag <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
>   # the color is corrected to fill by ggpairs
>   # to get desired output with color, it is changed back here.
>   if (! is.null(mapping$fill)) {
>     mapping$colour = mapping$fill
>     mapping$fill = NULL
>   }
>
>   ggplot(data, mapping) + geom_density(...) 
> }
>
> ggpairs(data, columns = 2:3, colour = "group", diag = list(continuous = "correct_diag_density"))
> ```
>
> Until the next release, you can leverage the eval process of ggpairs.
>   "ggally_FN_NAME" or "ggally_FN_NAMEDiag" are the naming conventions to
>   follow. The next release will allow for submission of custom functions
>   directly such as:
>
> ```
> ggpairs(data, columns = 2:3, colour = "group", diag = list(continuous = ggally_correct_diag_densityDiag))
> ```

See more details in their [github page](https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/101)